# When I delete a cell with Core data, same cell show twice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

When I delete a cell with Core data, I got a one problem. 
When I delete between cells, next cell of deleted cell becomes same after next cell. It looks like below.
[image]

It just look like. When I go out and back to table view, It deleted correctly.
But, when I delete the last cell, it looks good. It works well! It doesn't happened only this situation(deleting last cell) !

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        //FIXME: Delete 
        let quote:Quotes = quotes![indexPath.row]
        self.context.delete(quote)

        do {
            try self.context.save()
            self.quotes?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.tableview.beginUpdates()
    }

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.tableview.endUpdates()
    }
```

I Don't know what is the wrong, please tell me about this situation :(

My simulator is v10.1 and Xcode Version is 8.2.1

Comment: provide some screenshots

Comment: @GaneshKumar I just added it!

Comment: @lucy This is happened when you delete the cell or when you swipe to show to editing option?

Comment: @NiravD both of it. When I click delete button and swipe it , this is happened

Comment: instead of delete rows in tableview delete appropriate value in array then reload the tableview...

Comment: @lucy Add this method in your question `canEditRowAt` and `editActionsForRowAt`.

Comment: @Dhivya If you read question properly you can see that OP already deleting object from array using `self.quotes?.remove(at: indexPath.row)`

Comment: Agreed @NiravD but instead of this
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
we can reload the tableview with new data right

Comment: well...I got a solution... someone answered "I think cell height is too high" (now it's deleted) So, I changed cell height `view.frame.width` -> `20` worked well!!

Comment: @Dhivya No need to reload the whole tableView to remove one row. You can simply use deleteRows and its batter option,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is cell height. Cell height is too big compared to screen height.
When I change cell height, it works well.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {    
    return 20 //before: view.frame.width 
}
```

But, I'd like to spuare shape cell. So, I added refresh controller at the top.

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.996, green: 0.878, blue: 0.196, alpha: 1.00)
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableview.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
func refresh() {
    self.tableview.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

It's not perfect answer but, it can be the second best policy. If you have better than is way, please leave a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Blow Code works for me !

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      if editingStyle == .delete {
    //FIXME: Delete 
    let quote:Quotes = quotes![indexPath.row]
    self.context.delete(quote)

    do {
        try self.context.save()

        deleteRow(indexPath)

    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}


func deleteRow(indexPath : NSIndexPath){
  self.quotes?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, it still get same problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the call to `deleteRows` like this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

From [Apple UIKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates)

> If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid.

Comment: Thank u! I missed that info :( Sorry, now I updated about it! I handled it with two functions

Comment: If this worked for you, can you please accept this answer? Thanks.

Comment: `begin/endUpdates` is completely useless in this case (a single deletion operation).  See *...if you want subsequent insertion**s**, deletion, and selection operation**s** ... simultaneously* at the beginning of the Discussion. Besides the methods are called in the delegate methods anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was necessary which is why I said "Try" doing this. I couldn't recall having had to do this myself, but the vagueness of the documentation - "table attributes might become invalid" - suggested to me it might by necessary. I figured it was easy enough to try. I also don't see anything in the docs that says these statements are unnecessary if the changes are done within a tableview delegate method.

Comment: It's a question of a **single** `insert/delete/move` operation vs. **multiple** operations **simultaneously**. The OP uses `NSFetchedResultsController` which calls `controllerWillChangeContent` and `controllerDidChangeContent` always before and after the changes.